# Is there any way to get a function pointer from a &str type in rust which is provided by the use

Tags: function, rust, closures

Is there any way to get a function pointer from a &str type in rust which is provided by the use.
Example: use provides a name of a function *provided by the user* i need some way to call the function *preferably a closure or a function pointer*

Comment: Unless you've stripped your binary, you *could* abuse the symbol table to do that (although it would be a bad idea).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust is a static, compiled language. There is no access to functions by name at runtime. The functions may not even exist (they may be inlined, for example, or optimized away). Instead, what you need to do is create a HashMap of Strings to functions you would like to call at runtime, or use a `match` to dispatch by string.

Comment: Could you provide a example?

Comment: [Here's a demonstration of how one might use `HashMap`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=041f3197ec2ee43a46fd2b8c9dc3e9ee) (many variations are possible)